# VBA for automatic formula calculation in the range of cells after cell value input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for the code working on change of value basis, which does the following: 
after I type number in col A, column B would show 5% tax calculation and column C total with tax,

I know that I can use formula in Col B `=A1*0.05`  and `=A1+B1` in Col C but I have to copy the formulas and drag it down every time new row is added, I would like to automate that process.

Comment: You could just fill it down past the data.. `=IF(ISBLANK($A1), "", $A1*0.05)`

Comment: Or [format it as table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370). If you add a row to a table it automatically pulls down the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this Formulas "Col B =A1*0.05 and Col C =A1+B1" (dont forget to capture the row used on column A) in a event of selection change

Comment: This is exactly what OP is already doing, but doesn't want to have do do manually for every row in his sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Automating such a simple task seems like an overkill but it's easy enough to do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If (Not Intersect(Columns("A:A"), .Cells) Is Nothing) And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
            .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = .Value2 * 1.05
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```